# PHP File Upload upload the file even if statement is not correct

Tags: php, html, web, php-5.5

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="password" name="filepassword" id="filepassword">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $valueOne =trim($_POST["filepassword"]);
    if($valueOne != "1212"){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
        echo "file uploaded successfully !";
    }
    else{
        echo "file is not entered !";
    }
}
?>
```

No matter what the code inside the if(check) statement, file get uploaded

Comment: you want to upload or not if condition is true?

Comment: I want to upload if the condition is true ..

Comment: I think you should check $_FILES inseat POST

Comment: in my view you have to write if($valueOne == "1212"){  in place of if($valueOne != "1212"){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code as below:-

```
if(!empty($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["filepassword"]) && !empty($_FILES['fileToUpload'])){
    $valueOne =trim($_POST["filepassword"]);
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    if($valueOne == "1212"){ // if password is 1212 then file will upload.
    // make sure you want to check == or !=
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
          echo "file uploaded successfully !";
    }
    else{
          echo "file is not entered !";
    }   
}
```

Comment: it says file is not entered when you upload the file with correct password !

Comment: okay. then you should check **==** instead of **!=**. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: got it.. you have to change "$valueOne != "1212"" into "$valueOne == "1212""  ... not its workin g

Comment: check this link:- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Just Swap the code within if and else

```
if($valueOne != "1212"){
    echo "file is not entered !";
     }
     else{  
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
     echo "file uploaded successfully !";
     }
```